# Replace whole state of application with state of another commit

Tags: git, cherry-pick, merge-strategy

I'd like to do "the hardest version" of cherry-pick/merge/rebase/checkout, what means that state of app on my branch begins to look exactly like in the cherry-picked commit (but with keeping history of my branch). In fact I could duplicate my repo, delete everything in my branch and next copy whole content from duplicated version set to needed commit. But well, that's not handy and I believe there's some easier way.

I already tried `git cherry-pick <hash> --strategy-option theirs`, but that's not perfect, because it doesn't remove files not existing in cherry-picked commit, what results in big mess in my case.

So, how can I do this?

**Edit:** I clarified that I need also keep my history, what was not obvious first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a cherry-pick at all.  Don't use `git cherry-pick` to make it: use `git commit` to make it.  Here's a very simple recipe<sup>1</sup> to make it:

```
$ git checkout <branch>                # get on the target branch
$ cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)  # ensure you're at the top of the work-tree
$ git rm -r .                          # remove all tracked files from index and work-tree
$ git checkout <hash> -- .             # create every file anew from <hash>
$ git commit                           # make a new commit with all new info
```

If you want to copy the commit message and such from commit `<hash>`, consider adding `-c <hash>` to the `git commit` line.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is not the simplest, but it should be understandable.  The simpler ones use plumbing commands after the initial `git checkout`, e.g.:

```
git read-tree -u <hash>
git commit
```

or:

```
git merge --ff-only $(git commit-tree -p HEAD <hash>^{tree} < /tmp/commit-msg)
```

(untested and for the second one you'll have to construct a commit message).

#### Long

Remember that Git stores commits, with each commit being a complete snapshot of all source files, plus some metadata.  The metadata for each commit includes the name and email address of whoever makes the commit; a date-and-time-stamp for when the commit was made; a log message to say *why* the commit was made; and, crucially for Git, the hash ID of the *parent* of the commit.

Whenever you have the hash ID of some commit, we say that you are *pointing to* the commit.  If one commit has the hash ID of another commit, the commit with the hash ID points to the other commit.

What this means is that these hash IDs, embedded within each commit, form a backwards-looking chain.  If we use single letters to stand in for commits, or number them `C1`, `C2`, and so on in sequence, we get:

```
A <-B <-C <-D ... <-G <-H
```

or:

```
C1 <-C2 <-C3 ... <-C7 <-C8
```

The actual name of each commit is of course some big ugly hash ID, but using letters or numbers like this makes it much easier for us, as humans, to deal with them.  In any case, the key is that if we somehow save the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain, we end up with the ability to follow the rest of the chain backwards, one commit at a time.

The place we have Git store these hash IDs is in *branch names*.  So a branch name like `master` just stores the real hash ID of commit `H`, while `H` itself stores the hash ID of its parent `G`, which stores the hash ID of its parent `F`, and so on:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master
```

These backwards-looking links, from `H` to `G` to `F`, plus the snapshots saved with each commit plus the metadata about who made the commit and why, *are* the history in your repository.  To retain the history that ends in `H`, you simply need to make sure that the *next* commit, when you make it, has `H` as its parent:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

By making the new commit, Git changes the name `master` to remember the hash ID of new commit `I`, whose parent is `H`, whose parent is (still) `G`, and so on.

Your goal is to make commit `I` using the *snapshot* that's associated with some other commit, such as `K` below:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
   \
    J------K------L   <-- somebranch
```

Git actually builds new commits out of whatever is in the *index*, rather than what's in the source tree.  So we start with `git checkout master` to make commit `H` the current commit and `master` the current branch, which fills in the index and work-tree from the contents of commit `H`.

Next, we want the index to match commit `K`—with no other files than those that are in `K`—so we start by removing every file from the index.  For sanity (i.e., so that we can see what we're doing) we let Get do the same to the work-tree, which it does automatically.  So we run `git rm -r .` after making sure that `.` refers to the entire index / work-tree pair, by making sure we're at the top of the work-tree and not in some sub-directory / sub-folder.

Now only untracked files remain in our work-tree.  We can remove these too if we like, using plain `rm` or `git clean`, though in most cases they're harmless.  If you wish to remove them, feel free to do that.  Then we need to fill in the index—the work-tree once again comes along for the ride—from commit `K`, so we run `git checkout <hash-of-K> -- .`.  The `-- .` is important: it tells Git *don't **switch** commits, just extract everything from the commit named here.*  Our index and work-tree now match commit `K`.

(If commit `K` has *all* files that we have in `H`, we could skip the `git rm` step.  We only need the `git rm` to *remove* files that are in `H` but are not in `K`.)

Last, now that we have the index (and work-tree) matching commit `K`, we're safe to make a new commit that is like `K` but does not connect *to* `K`.

#### If you want a merge, use `git merge --no-commit`

The above sequence results in:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
   \
    J-------K-----L   <-- somebranch
```

where the *saved source snapshot* in commit `I` exactly matches that in commit `K`.  However, the history produced by reading `master`, finding that it points to `I`, and then reading commit `I` and on backwards to `H` and `G` and `F` and so on, never *mentions* commit `K` at all.

You might instead want a history that looks like this:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
   \         /
    J-------K-----L   <-- somebranch
```

Here, commit `I` reaches back to *both* commits `H` *and* `K`.

Making this variant of commit `I` is a little trickier, because aside from using the `git commit-tree` plumbing command, the only way to *make* commit `I` is to use `git merge`.

Here, the easy way is to run `git merge -s ours --no-commit`, as in:

```
$ git merge -s ours --no-commit <hash>  # start the merge but don't finish it
$ git rm -r .                           # discard everything
$ git checkout <hash> -- .              # replace with their content
$ git commit                            # and now finish the merge
```

We use `-s ours` here to make things go faster and more smoothly.  What we're building is really the result of `git merge -s theirs`, except for the fact that there is no `git merge -s theirs`.  The `-s ours` means *ignore their commit, just keep the contents from our commit `H`.*  Then we throw that out and replace it with the content from their commit `K`, and then we finish the merge to get a merge commit `I` that points to both `H` and `K`.

As before, there *are* plumbing command tricks that make this even easier.  They're just not *obvious* unless you understand the low level storage format that Git uses internally.  The "remove everything, then check out a different commit's contents" method is really obvious, and is easy to remember.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `git reset --soft`. First, merge...  doesn't matter the strategy or results. If you have conflicts, it doesn't matter... add all files and save (don't worry... we will amend with the right content in just a second).

Now, checkout the revision that you want to take content from. If it is a branch, use `--detach`. Now, `git reset --soft` to the original branch (where we did our merge before).

And now to finish the trick run `git commit --amend --no-edit` and you are done. If you like the results, move the branch pointer of the original branch with `git branch -f the-original-branch` and you are done.

**Original recibe, without saving history of the other branch**
What you want to do is `git reset --soft`. Check out the revision( or branch with --detach) that you want the other branch to look like (content-wise). Then do `git reset --soft the-other-branch`. That will set the branch *pointer* to this revision or branch, the working tree will be just like the one we checked out before and all the differences between them will be on index. Now, when you commit, you will get a single revision where the branch will look just like the original one you checked out first.... if you like the end result, move the branch pointer and check it out.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not precise enough. I edited my question, because in fact I need also keep history of my branch. But yeah, assuming that I want my whole branch to look **really** like from the cherry-picked commit, including branch history - your solution is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git checkout --orphan new-branch-name
$ git cherry-pick <hash>
```

Comment: It doesn't solve my problems. First of all, I'd like to do this on my current branch, and admittedly I could merge my new branch to the old, but I still have troubles with remaining untracked files (I mean: untracked by cherry-picked commit).

Comment: sorry, I probably misunderstood your situation